# DetailApiViewset with classed based api view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create detail API viewset but for now, I am getting page not found whenever I go to my "matches/api/matches/1/". ListCreateAPIView works fine.

Here are my viewsets:

```py
class MatchViewset(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        header_token = self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        print(header_token)
        if header_token is not None:
            try:
                token = sub('Token ', '', self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None))
                token_obj = Token.objects.get(key=token)
                self.request.user = token_obj.user
            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        print(self.request.user)
        return Match.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)


class MatchDetailViewset(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Match.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer
```

and routers:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'matches', matches_views.MatchViewset, base_name="matches")
```

and urls:

```py
app_name = 'matches'

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs here: [Routers usage](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage)

after the `router.register(r'matches', matches_views.MatchViewset, base_name="matches")` you must give

`urlpatterns = router.urls`

I guess this would solve the issue

Comment: I used include function in my urls file so I guess is not that. I just added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `MatchDetailViewset` is not registered in urlpatterns, that's why you're getting a 404 error
2. It seems like DRF router not support registering multiple viewset with the same prefix.
   So maybe you should try something like this:

```
class MatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer
    queryset = Match.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        header_token = self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        print(header_token)
        if header_token is not None:
            try:
                token = sub('Token ', '', self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None))
                token_obj = Token.objects.get(key=token)
                self.request.user = token_obj.user
            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        print(self.request.user)

        # customize the queryset for listview
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(creator=self.request.user)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```